# Running a sequelize query inside a forEach loop. Can not process result

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm running this sequelize query which returns some forum posts. And for each of the results I' running a 2nd query which gets me the categories/tags of each forum posts. Now, the forEach loop is ending before all queries are run because it's asynchronous I know that part. How do I handle this properly and do what I'm trying to do? I want to attach the tags/categories array to each of the posts and send the array of posts to the ejs view and call next();

I have tried promise.all() and async-await, I do get the categories separately that way. But I want the categories to be attached to each of the post objects.

```
Forum.findAll({
    attributes: ["f_post_id", "f_post_title", "like_count", "createdAt"],
    limit: limitPost.FORUM,
    subQuery: false,
    raw: true,
    group: ['forum.f_post_title'],

    include: [{
        attributes: ["user_name"],
        model: User,
        required: true, // returns everything in a clean single object format
                        // setting it to false, results in nested arrays
    }, {
        attributes: [[Sequelize.fn("COUNT", Sequelize.col("forum_answers.answer_id")), "ansCount"]],
        model: ForumAnswer,
        required: true,
    }]
})
    .then(fetchedPost => {

        fetchedPost.forEach(post => {

            ForumTag.findAll({
                attributes: [],
                raw: true,

                where: {
                    f_post_id: post.f_post_id,
                },
                include: [{
                    attributes: ["tag_name"],
                    model: Tag,
                    required: true,
                }]
            })
                .then(postTags => {

                    post.tags = postTags.map(postTag => postTag["tag.tag_name"]);

                })
                .catch(err => console.log(err));

        });

        res.locals.fetchedPost = fetchedPost;
        next();

    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

This is the expected result below:

```
{ 
  f_post_id: 1,
  f_post_title: 'learn js',
  like_count: 12,
  createdAt: 2019-05-19T00:00:00.000Z,
  'user.user_name': 'mrscx',
  'forum_answers.ansCount': 3,
  tags: [ 'JavaScript', 'Database' ] 
}
```

But tags are not being attached because of the forEach loop ending.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the looks of it, the issue might be with the way you are processing the promises. You are not actually waiting for the promises in the `forEach` loop to be processed, but instead are returning the result before that. One way to fix that would be something like:

```
Forum.findAll({
    attributes: ["f_post_id", "f_post_title", "like_count", "createdAt"],
    limit: limitPost.FORUM,
    subQuery: false,
    raw: true,
    group: ['forum.f_post_title'],

    include: [{
        attributes: ["user_name"],
        model: User,
        required: true, // returns everything in a clean single object format
                        // setting it to false, results in nested arrays
    }, {
        attributes: [[Sequelize.fn("COUNT", Sequelize.col("forum_answers.answer_id")), "ansCount"]],
        model: ForumAnswer,
        required: true,
    }]
})
    .then(fetchedPost => {

        return Promise.all(fetchedPost.map(post => 
            ForumTag.findAll({
                attributes: [],
                raw: true,

                where: {
                    f_post_id: post.f_post_id,
                },
                include: [{
                    attributes: ["tag_name"],
                    model: Tag,
                    required: true,
                }]
            })
                .then(postTags => {

                    post.tags = postTags.map(postTag => postTag["tag.tag_name"]);
                    return post.save();
                })
                .catch(err => console.log(err));

        }).then(() => {
          res.locals.fetchedPost = fetchedPost;
          next();
      });
    })
```

There are also more elegant ways to do this sort of thing I'm sure. But this is the least amount of modification to the original code.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You're a life saver. It worked. Minor edit => ForumTag.findAll <= added a return statement before this and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

The `findAll()` call is async, so the `forEach` invokes `ForumTag.findAll()` for each post but returns immediately before the modifications could take effect. Also, you need to call `save()` method on a model after modification to make that permanent (e.g `post.save()` after `post.tags = ...`)

You could try something like this:

```
let promises = [];

fetchedPost.forEach(post => {

  ForumTag.findAll({
    attributes: [],
    raw: true,

    where: {
      f_post_id: post.f_post_id,
    },
    include: [{
      attributes: ["tag_name"],
      model: Tag,
      required: true,
    }]
  })
    .then(postTags => {

       post.tags = postTags.map(postTag => postTag["tag.tag_name"]);
       promises.push(post.save());

  })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

});

Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
  res.locals.fetchedPost = fetchedPost;
  next();
}).catch(err => {
  throw err;
});
```